# Color area under the curve

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an imported SVG graph in Illustrator CC like the one below. I want to color the area under the curve (the area under the curve that the red arrow is pointing to). I tried drawing new paths and so on and it's been a mess. Can anyone shed some light on how could this be done in the most efficient way? Thanks a lot in advance.

Jon

[image: example]

Comment: Hi Jon, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty:

1. be sure that the line in your graph is ungrouped from all other elements;
2. draw a rectangle that has its lower left corner in your origin and extends *above* the graph line, but just short of extends to the right of it;
3. arrange the rectangle behind your graph line;
4. copy the graph line: <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Edit > Copy</kbd>;
5. paste in front: <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Edit > Paste in Front</kbd>;
6. select both the front copy of the graph line and the rectangle;
7. select the `Shape builder` tool <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>;
8. click the area below the line, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click the area above the line and the line itself;
9. colour your area to taste.